# fastest way to query data from active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to query "member-of" data about a user and I'm looking for the fastest way to do so in C#.

I've tried IsInRole(), PrincipalSearcher and linq and the results where far better for the IsInRole method.

Still from what I've heard, an LDAP query of some sort has to be faster then multiple IsInRole callings, I just can't find one.

if anyone has the fastest way (or even faster then the IsInRole() method) to get this information
from the AD, please help me.

thanks,
   Matt

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? get all the groups a user is member of? get membership of a subset of groups, including nested groups?

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative to `IsInRole` is checking if a user is member of a group with a DirectorySearcher, using this ldap filter (check [search filter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
"(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SomeGroup,DC=X,DC=Y)"
```

Also, you must specify the user as search base.
I don't know, however, if performance-wise this is better than `IsInRole`...